# Why is React Native App.js navigation undefined in App.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

*export default function App ({navigation})*

There is a function that starts with and contains <Stack.Navigator>.

But when I want to use the navigation feature and use "navigation.navigate ('Lead') in onPress

*TypeError: undefined is not an object evaluating react navigation*

I get an error. My English is not very good. Please help me on this topic. Now I'm adding the sample codes to you.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, AsyncStorage, Alert, View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { ApplicationProvider, Layout, Input, Button, Text, Spinner, IconRegistry, Icon } from '@ui-kitten/components';
import { EvaIconsPack } from '@ui-kitten/eva-icons';
import * as eva from '@eva-design/eva';
import LinkingConfiguration from './navigation/LinkingConfiguration';
import * as axios from 'axios';
import Base64 from './components/Base64';
import LeadScreen from './screens/LeadScreen';
import AddLeadScreen from './screens/AddLeadScreen';
import TabBarIcon from './components/TabBarIcon';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import CampaignsScreen from './screens/CampaignsScreen';
import MenuScreen from './screens/MenuScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App({ navigation }) {  
  const logout = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('token');    
    dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_OUT' });
  };
  
  return (    
    <>
      <IconRegistry icons={EvaIconsPack} />
      <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light}>        
          <Layout style={styles.container}>
            <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
              <NavigationContainer linking={LinkingConfiguration}>
                <Stack.Navigator>
                  {state.isLoading ? (
                    // We haven't finished checking for the token yet
                    <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} /> 
                    ) : state.token == null ? (
                    // No token found, user isn't signed in
                    <>
                      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{ title: 'Oturum Açın' }} />                      
                    </>
                    ) : (
                    // User is signed in
                    <>
                    <Stack.Screen name="User" component={UserScreen} options={{
                        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#e8a200' },
                        headerTintColor: 'white',
                        headerTitleStyle: { color: '#fff' },
                        headerRight: () => (
                          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.4} underlayColor='transparent' onPress={() => logout() } style={{ marginRight: 12 }}>
                            <Icon
                              style={styles.icon}
                              fill='#FFFFFF'
                              name='power-outline'
                            />
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                        )
                      }} />

                      <Stack.Screen name="Lead" component={LeadScreen} options={{
                        title: 'Müşteri Adayları',
                        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#e8a200' },
                        headerTintColor: 'white',
                        headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#fff' },
                        headerRight: () => (
                          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.4} underlayColor='transparent' onPress={ () => console.log(navigation) } style={{ marginRight: 12 }}>
                            <Icon
                              style={styles.icon}
                              fill='#FFFFFF'
                              name='plus-outline'
                            />
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                      )}} />

                      <Stack.Screen name="AddLead" component={AddLeadScreen} options={{ title: 'Müşteri Adayı Ekle' }} />
                    </>
                  )}              
                </Stack.Navigator>
              </NavigationContainer>
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        </Layout>
      </ApplicationProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you share more sample codes?

Comment: Of course, I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think the `navigation` here is unnecessary, you can remove it.

```
export default function App({ navigation }) {
```

In your screen components, ie. `UserScreen`, you can use navigation like so

```
function UserScreen({navigation}) {
  // ...some codes
  navigation.navigate('WHERE_TO_GO');
  // ...some other codes
}
```

You could also use navigation without passing it to the props.

First you need to import useNavigation

```
import { useNavigation } from '@'react-navigation/native'
```

And then, in your component

```
function UserScreen() {
  const nav = useNavigation();
  // ...some codes
  nav.navigate('WHERE_TO_GO');
  // ...some other codes
}
```

You could get more details here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/

For the onPress function of `Lead` screen,

```
<Stack.Screen name="Lead" component={LeadScreen} options={({ navigation }) => ({
  title: 'Müşteri Adayları',
  headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#e8a200' },
  headerTintColor: 'white',
  headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#fff' },
  headerRight: () => (
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.4} underlayColor='transparent' onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('WHERE_TO_GO') } style={{ marginRight: 12 }}>
      <Icon
        style={styles.icon}
        fill='#FFFFFF'
        name='plus-outline'
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
)})} />
```

Comment: But I have to use it in export. It's not an external function. Please review the code carefully.

Comment: Since you seem to be using React Navigation 5, you can still use navigation without passing it through props. Let me edit the codes.

Comment: Thanks, I'm waiting.

Comment: Sorry, you are still doing this through an external function. I have nothing to do with UserScreen. I want to use it on onPress in export default in <Stack.Screen name = "Lead" options. Please review the code thoroughly.

Comment: Ohh. I am only using the UserScreen as an example sorry. Let me put the codes for the onPress.

Comment: I added a missing bracket, please check it again @Dodiş

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the navigation or rout prop into options in the stack.screen like this

```
options={({navigation})=>({
    'Your code here'
})}
```

I have edited it with your code for you.

```
        <Stack.Screen name="Lead" component={LeadScreen}
         options={({ navigation }) => ({
             title: 'Müşteri Adayları',
             headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#e8a200' },
             headerTintColor: 'white',
             headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#fff' },
             headerRight: () => (
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.4} 
                   underlayColor='transparent' onPress={() => 
                   console.log(navigation)} style={{ marginRight: 12 }}>
                    <Icon
                       style={styles.icon}
                          fill='#FFFFFF'
                          name='plus-outline'
                      />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  )
         })} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `useLinkProps` to solve this issue:

```
import { useLinkProps } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

And this is an example on how to write code which uses it:

```
const LinkButton = ({ to, action, children, ...rest }) => {
  const { onPress, ...props } = useLinkProps({ to, action });
```

Comment: Sorry, my friend, I want to use the navigation variable in onPress. Can you please review the code?

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you for the explaination will definetly keep that in mind. Working hard towards  those upvotes. lol...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried everything but this worked for me.
Make a function in your app.js and pass props then access using props.navigation like below.

```
function CustomDrawerContent**(props)** {
.....
    
  logOut = () => {
    AsyncStorage.clear(); 
    **props.navigation.navigate("Login");**
  };
.....
}
```